I am using =SUMPRODUCT(--(D12:V12<>E12:W12-1))+1-COUNTIF(D12:W12,"") to count consecutive dates. Need to not count dates more than 12 months old
I am using =SUMPRODUCT(--(D12:V12<>E12:W12-1))+1-COUNTIF(D12:W12,"") to count consecutive dates. Need to not count dates more than 12 months old. I am using =COUNTIF(D12:W12,">"&EDATE(TODAY(),-12)) for single dates and this works great. I can not find a way of excluding consequtive dates that are more than 12 months old from showing in my results.
I have tried let and Xlookup combinations to no avail
